# How is the pushd directory stack stored?

Tags: pushd

In a related question [somebody states](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/556729/202178) that the directory stack of the `pushd` command is emptied when your shell terminates. But *how* is the stack actually stored? I use [fish](https://fishshell.com/) instead of bash and the commands work the same way. I would assume `pushd` (and `popd`) works independently of the shell you're using. Or do both shells have their own implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The directory stack is not stored anywhere permanent. Shell just keeps it in process memory, in an array `DIRSTACK` (which has restrictions on user modification). It's not even strictly a stack -- bash and ksh allow you to rotate it left and right by specified counts, too.

In Bash, the `dirs` command clears or shows the stack in various ways, `popd` removes any specified dir, and `pushd` adds a dir or rotates the stack to change to any of the dirs already stored.

The pushd stack is not "cleared" as such. Pushd is a shell built-in, not an external command (which would not be able to change the shell's own environment). Each shell retains its own pushd data, and when that shell process goes away, the contents are just discarded.